# Adding replyTo in mail.php not working in Laravel 5.1

Tags: email, laravel-5.1

I have a laravel 5.1 app. I am sending emails in several places. When I add replyTo like below it works.

```
Mail::queue('emails.password_update', ['user' => $user, 'password' => $password], function($message) use ($user){
            $message->to($user->email, $user->name)->subject('Account Password Updated');
            $message->replyTo('noreply@divostar.com', 'DivoStar');
            $message->priority(1);
        });
```

But, given that emails are sent in several places and the replyTo email is same. I don't want to repeat it everywhere. What I have done is add an entry in mail.php like below:

```
'replyTo' => ['address' => 'noreply@divostar.com', 'name' => 'DivoStar'],
```

and send the mail as such:

```
 Mail::queue('emails.password_update', ['user' => $user, 'password' => $password], function($message) use ($user){
                $message->to($user->email, $user->name)->subject('Account Password Updated');
                $message->priority(1);
            });
```

When I do this, it doesn't work. There is no Reply-To in the mail. Why is the entry in mail.php not read?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravel 5.1 doesn't implement a global replyTo using the config. You can see from the source code here https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Mail/MailServiceProvider.php#L22

The best way would be to add a config entry on in config/mail.php

```
'replyTo' => ['address' => 'noreply@divostar.com', 'name' => 'DivoStar'],
```

And where ever you send a mail, do

```
Mail::queue('emails.password_update', ['user' => $user, 'password' => $password], function($message) use ($user){
        $message->to($user->email, $user->name)->subject('Account Password Updated');
        $message->replyTo(config('mail.replyTo.address'), config('mail.replyTo.name');
        $message->priority(1);
    });
```

Another alternative solution would be to write a custom wrapper class call it "MailerService" which would just call Default Laravel mailer but this time with a custom reply to.

Answer (score 0):

Since Laravel 5.3 you can add a global reply to to your config like this:

```
'reply_to' => ['address' => 'noreply@divostar.com', 'name' => 'DivoStar'],
```